# 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in timestamp

Tags: php, laravel-4

I was trying to seed databases in my project. When I did, only 'title' and 'post' fields are inserted, 'Created_at' and 'Updated_at' are not are not changed and show as 0000-00-00 00:00:00. I also tried with time() too. It properly work in '`php artisan tink`' but still no results are changed in database.

```
<?php

class QuestionsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {

        DB::table('questions')->truncate();

        $questions = array(
            'title' => 'Simple Question Title',
            'post' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor',
            'created_at' => time()
        );

        // Uncomment the below to run the seeder
         DB::table('questions')->insert($questions);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `new DateTime()` !
Hope this 'll hep

Answer (score 4):

by using

```
'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
```

you format the value returned by `time()` as a mySql timestamp

Answer (score 1):

The updating and inserting new timestamps in database problem faced by many users and they want to insert the date and also update the record. The are many ways to do that but I like the way done by database himself. As in MySQL altering the table as

```
 ALTER TABLE `talbename` 
   ADD `updatedon` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
   NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

This will create the new column in database and every time the record is updated or inserted the timestamps would be recorded itself. No, need to do things in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The OO way (using  DateTime)

```
$now = new DateTime();

$questions = array(
            'title' => 'Simple Question Title',
            'post' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor',
            'created_at' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent also handle like timestamps automatically. Code would be as following;

```
public function run()
    {
        DB::table('questions')->truncate();

        Question::create(array(
            'title' => 'Sample Question Title',
            'post' => 'Lorem ipsum dollar'
        ));

    }
```